# Some NEF files are identified as folders

Tags: windows-7, camera-raw

I'm not sure what has happened, but some NEF files are identified as folders on my backup disk by Win 7.

I'm not able to read them with a hex editor, as they will not open folders (naturally).

What happened, and how can I recover my NEF files?

Comment: Agreed on asking on SuperUser.  This is definitely not a photography question.  That is very odd though and I also have no particular insight other than to ask if you are sure that that is what happened and not that you simply ended up with a folder with the same name somehow.  The structure of a file and a folder are fundamentally different in most file systems with a folder just being an index that can't have any data associated with it other than typical folder meta-data.  It would actually have to be a file system corruption (and a very very weird one) to have this happen.

Comment: Have you run `chkdsk` on that drive/partition lately?

Comment: Yes, `chkdsk` didn't find anything. I never name folders the same as my file names, Because of this, I'm not able to copy folders from one location to another (disk) if it contains these corrupted files.